# Response is not being returned due to cookies

Tags: jmeter

[image]See below the issue details in detail
1st-time execution of script getting a response for sampler 3 ( see below screenshot

2nd-time execution of script getting a response( text only) for sampler 3 see below screenshot
[image]
While executing Jmeter script by check-marking the "clear cookies each iteration" it is getting passed, but when I run it again it is getting failed and Vice Versa.

same as above While executing Jmeter script by UNcheck marking the "clear cookies each iteration" it is getting passed, but when I run it again it is getting failed and Vice Versa.

Comment: What does fail exactly?

Comment: for the success sampler response come like as below

<RESPONSE> bulk response data will come here/></RESPONSE>

for the failure sampler response come like as below

<RESPONSE>

due to that the following samplers are failing

Comment: for the failure sampler response come like as below

<RESPONSE>  text only